# Doctrine - Prevent double flush on using identity through foreign entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

I've got 2 entities - `TestUser` and `TestAddress`. Address has OneToOne relation with User and it's primary key is also foreign key to User.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TestUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TestAddress
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TestUser")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @param $user
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

When I try to save both entities through entityManager I get an Exception.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

$user = new TestUser();
$address = new TestAddress();
$address->setUser($user);

$em->persist($user);
$em->persist($address);
$em->flush();
```

Exception:

```
Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: The given entity of type 'Entity\TestAddress' (Entity\TestAddress@000000004fcda1bf000000002f07b49b) has no identity/no id values set. It cannot be added to the identity map.
```

Only way to save both entities is "flush" with User and then persist and flush with address.

```
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
$em->persist($address);
$em->flush();
```

**Question:** Is there way to use autoincrement on TestUser id and save TestUser and TestAddress entities with one flush?

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestAddress
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TestUser", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $user;
```

Comment: how do you persisting entities in this case? You should persist address, user will be persisted automatically. If you want to make it other way around, then move mapping to user entity

Comment: I've added to user ```@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TestUser", cascade={"persist"})```
Saving with 
```$user = new TestUser();
        $address = new TestAddress();
        $address->setUser($user);
        $em->persist($address);
        $em->flush();
```

Error: The given entity of type 'Entity\TestAddress' (Entity\TestAddress@000000002eaf1c740000000011c59edd) has no identity/no id values set

Comment: Why do you have `* @ORM\Id` in `user` mapping? And show how id of address is mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not even an answer to your question, but IMO you should rethink the purpose of this schema choice when the ID of the Address entity must correspond to the ID of the User entity. I do not think this is necessary and you would be better off by going with separate foreign key and primary key fields on Address entity.

However one other thing you could try is making the relationship bi-directional, that is defining the testAddress variable on the User object and then adding the corresponding mapping information to it:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="TestAddress", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $testAddress;
```

then you will probably also need to create the setTestAddress() method on the user entity, and set the user object for TestAddress explicitly in there:

```
public function setTestAddress($address)
{ 
  $address->setUser($this);
  $this->testAddress = $address;
}
```

then you could call $user->setTestAddress($address) and try flushing only the user entity:

```
$user = new TestUser();
$address = new TestAddress();
$user->setTestAddress($address);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

I am not quite familiar with the order in which doctrine persists entities, but by having the entity be persisted by the TestUser entity and not the other way around(as was suggested) User should be persisted first and than its ID added to the Address before it is even persisted.

I didn't test the code so there might be some errors in it.